# Would a SIGNAL - GND - SIGNAL - 3.3v PCB stack okay?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

The Typical 4 layer PCB stack up would be

1. Primary Signal
2. GND
3. Vcc
4. Secondary signal

And i have always used this on my 4 layer projects. On this current project however the Back side of the PCB is visible so i that it would be slightly more neat to look at (especially the texts wont have a slight wave to them) if i placed the secondary signal on layer 3 and Vcc on layer 4. There are no components on layer 4 and other traces as well so it is a solid unbroken plane.

So the stack up would now be

1. Primary Signal
2. GND
3. Secondary Signal
4. Vcc

All the signal types in my circuit are digital, and the protocols that will pass on the secondary layer are SPI and some LED signals

Would this stackup be okay?

Comment: It's OK if you are happy that the design is good. I say this because if there are a lot of internal connections made then you cannot easily cut tracks and solder bodgy fix items to them.

Comment: The one layer between power and ground planes is influenced by activity between those rails since it sits in the middle of the electric field between those rails/planes, if emi or low noise is a concern.

Comment: @Andyaka for debugging purposes, the fabricator I am using dont use blind vias so the traces will have to come up back to the top layer. But aside from that I do have have a prototype that i am satisfied with hopefully its the final design. (If there is some it will be aesthestic changes).

Comment: If it doesn't, just re-label the Gerbers and have it remade with a different stacking. No big deal.

Comment: @DKNguyen I dont seem to get what you are saying sir, can you explain it a different way?. Are you taking about EMI being induced to the singal traces or EMI being emittedd by the whole board? Since mostly if not all of the traces are digital it should not be a problem?

Comment: @BrianDrummond The shipping cost is the primary reason why im making sure, the boards are almost dirt cheap (4$) and shipping around (15$) plus it will take days again to arrive

Comment: Order both boards and combine shipping?

Comment: Both. An electric field will form in the dieelectric between a power plane and nearest ground plane and anything sitting in between will be subject to this. You can get away with it if your circuit is not demanding but make no mistake, you are sacrificing functionality for aesthetics. A board still working is not the same as having good EMI. You can have one without the other.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Touche... that is indeed clever.

Comment: @DKNguyen I agree you on that . The board draws less than 500mA. So I am Subjecting those signal lines to EMI, Does it help that i have signal TVS on the circuit?

Comment: @DrakeJest It does not.

Comment: EMI between the planes is not an issue, the electric fields are orthogonal. In fact I'd expect the shielding for these signals to be excellent, so they pick up less noise from the environment.

Comment: If you care about making it neat to look at, consider a more opaque soldermask color instead. Plain black is pretty good at hiding traces, and matte black makes it nigh impossible to see the traces under it (very frustrating to someone trying to reverse-engineer a circuit, but probably a good thing for you). Your PCB fab might charge a bit more for the unusual color though, especially the matte one.

Comment: Watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySuUZEjARPY&list=PLlD-hnyodqSf7D9zPVviYaOaDZnWxkDYx&index=21&t=3463s

Comment: @DKNguyen So i pretty much watched the whole thing starting from where you linked. And it looks like my stack up is tiny bit better than SIG-GND-PWR-SIG. It pretty hard to get his best case scenario where PWR and GND are on the outer layers since the components are on there. 4 layer is just not a sufficient layer. He said layers 2 and 3 are a major no no on gnd and power and instead place it on the other layers but that is so hard with components especially if they are on both sides. The best i can come up with is - SIG/PWR-GND-SIG/GND-PWR

Comment: @DKNguyen Thank you very much for that video by the it was so educational. I learned from there